# Query a relationship with where - let result affect parent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I query a relationship:

```
return User::with(array('product' => function($q){
        $q->where('published', 1);
    }))->get();
```

If a product is not published, the relationship is null.

If the product is not published, I also want to not return the user.

For example, the query should get all users who have a published product. If the user does not have a published product, do not return them.

Is this possible? Or will I just have to do some checking on the view and not output the user if product is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly you want to return only users that have a product that is published?

If so you're looking for the `whereHas()` function, this allows you to return results of the parent model based on parameters of the relation.

```
return User::whereHas('product', function($query)
{
    $query->where('published', true);
})->get();
```